# css image cut background transparent

Tags: css, background-image, transparent

I need get from a CMS the image and use in next section, side by side of promotion text (grey space), but i've no idea how to create the next effect:
[image: css needed]

Like you can see, square starts in top of left side and the go little down until the right side, in left side we have the vice-versa example of the effect i need.

Notes:

- Original image from CMS is a square, i need create the "cut" effect using css if possible
- Solution need to be compatible with ie9+, ff, chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need a background image and I'm assuming you want text to float over the gray part, you'll need to do something different than what was proposed by @seanlevan.

I've added some background images and text for demonstration purposes.

```css
/* IE9+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1200-800-9.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}


.wrapper {
    padding-top:50px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 750px;
    min-width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.skew-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(2.5deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(2.5deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(2.5deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(2.5deg);
    transform: skewY(2.5deg);
}
.skew-container:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-800-600-3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom left;
    z-index: -1;
}
.skew-container:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-index: -1;
}
.text {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 2em;
    margin-left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-2.5deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-2.5deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-2.5deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-2.5deg);
    transform: skewY(-2.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="skew-container">
        <div class="text">
            <h2>San Fran Flatbread &amp; Sauce</h2>
            <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet picanha pariatur in jowl. Prosciutto tongue cupidatat ex. Rump swine sausage shank ribeye ex minim consequat magna chuck meatball kevin pork chop in. Pariatur minim bacon tongue, sausage ut veniam cupim short loin.</p>
            <a href="#">Get the recipe</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically how this works is that the skew-container has a fixed height that is slightly bigger than its wrapper container.  By adding some top padding to the wrapper setting its overflow to hidden, you can push the skew container down so that the bottom of the div is hidden giving it a flat bottom.

Next, I used two pseudo elements to fill the container, but you don't have to make them pseudo elements if you want to have more flexibility to add the images dynamically with an inline style ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/483k4w8s/4/)).  Each of these is 50% the width of the parent skew container. By positioning them absolutely, they can be laid out side-by-side.  With a z-index of -1, they will be behind the text.

Finally, you want to cancel the skew on the text div by using negative skew values.  I gave the text container 50% width, floated it left and used margin-left of 50% to offset it so that it fit in the right gray area.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it was accomplished in pure CSS, it more likely used a background image with transparency to accomplish that effect. I've seen the cut effect used in many instances.

However, I *will* create a CSS version and post it here, because it *is* very possible.

Here is an example of it using the CSS3 property `skew` that I just programmed:

http://jsfiddle.net/35s9dk25/7/

It can be adjusted to fit your needs.

Mark this answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: Original image from CMS is a square, i need create the "cut" effect using css if possible

Comment: firefox 35, ie9&10, don't suport, only chrome :( @seanlevan